# Some services on debian 9.0, can not resolve domain names

Tags: debian, dns, resolv.conf, stunnel

Recently, after a dist-upgrade to Debian 9.0, I happened to notice that [`danted`](https://www.inet.no/dante/) (a socks v5 proxy server) and [`stunnel4`](http://www.stunnel.org) (an SSL/TLS tunneling service) services can not resolve domain names.

In `danted` logs:

```
request was not performed due to error: could not resolve hostname "www.google.com": Name or service not known
```

In `stunnel` logs:

```
Error resolving "www.stunnel.org": Neither nodename nor servname known (EAI_NONAME)
```

If I change the system user that the service is running under (for `danted` it is `proxy`, and for `stunnel` is `stunnel4`), to `root` and restart the service, it works fine.

- ordinary users can ping/resolve domain names.
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` are world readable.
- even `su`ing to system user, you can ping/resolve domain names:

  ```
  # su - -s /bin/sh -c "getent ahosts  www.stunnel.org" proxy 
  207.192.69.165  STREAM linode.mirt.net
  207.192.69.165  DGRAM  
  ...
  ```
- the content of `resolv.conf`:

  ```
  nameserver 127.0.0.1
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 208.67.222.222
  nameserver 208.67.220.220
  ```

  I use `dnsmasq`.

I'm not sure, what to do next.

Comment: what is the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: updated to add the content of the `resolv.conf`.

Comment: so user ``danted`` do not have access to network? Could be either selinux or iptables -m owner issue. Disable selinux and check your iptables -l

Comment: selinux is disabled, and there is no owner checking in iptables.

Comment: one thing though, `stunnel` works under the system user `stunnel4`, it just cannot resolve domain names ( mostly for it's socks v5 functionality ).

Comment: Hypothesis: service is started before resolv.conf is populated, and does not subsequently call `res_init()`.  Can you rule this out, by showing that keeping the user as `stunnel4` and restarting it still causes DNS failures?  Other services like ssh have `After=network.service` in the service file, but I don't think stunnel4 does.

Comment: Put google DNS then openDNS on the top of your `resolv.conf` file . The `nameserver 127.0.0.1` on the bottom.

Comment: @sourcejedi restarting services did not help. I tried it multiple time.

Comment: @GAD3R I did that, even I turned off the dnsmasq service, but still no luck.